# How to remove group from user in auth0

Tags: authentication, auth0

I am using auth0 for user security purpose. One user can have different application (Group) access.
All application having admin who can see all users belongs to their particular group.

E.g. 
UserA is in group1, group2 and group3.

UserB is in group1, group2.

Now, When Group1 admin logs in, he can see all users belongs to group1 (UserA, UserB). If admin remove UserA,, then only Group1 should remove from UserA profile.

Currently, If I remove user by using his ID, It's removing from auth0 itself.

How to remove group from use?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using version 2 of the Auth0 Authorization extension you can [enable the extension API](https://auth0.com/docs/extensions/authorization-extension#enabling-api-access) functionality which would allow you programmatic control over the information managed by the extension, including the ability to manage groups.

> The Authorization Dashboard can optionally enable API access which will allow you to automate provisioning and query the authorization context of your users in real time.

Comment: I am following article, But when I try to call api with user token, It's giving me Invalid user error. I am calling "https://<<Domain>>o/adf6e2f2b84784b57522e3b19dfc9201/api/groups" and in header I am paasing my token with authorization attribute. I am using POSTMAN tool

Comment: Are you able to perform any call to the extension API or they all fail? From the API explorer docs available within the extension the request to remove a member from a group would be something similar to `DELETE /api/groups/[group_id]/members` and in the request body there would be an array specifying the members to be removed.